# Using java stream and collect for a generic type

Tags: java, lambda

I am converting a list of strings to a list of a specific type. The list of strings can be converted to the other type with the help of gson since the strings are deserialized objects. I am using a lambda function to make the conversion.

My current code looks like:

```
List<String> myObject = myMethod.get(...);
Type typeObject= new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
List<T> myTransformedObject = myObject.stream()
                                .map(x-> gson.fromJson(x, typeObject))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

i get an error saying - "No instances of type variables exist so that Object confirms to T.

What am I missing?

Comment: In that case do I have to change the collectors to the generic type as well?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with streams, and everything to do with  `new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType()` not working...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your code generic, you should use a method with a [**bounded type parameter**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) as next:

```
public <T> List<T> transform(Class<T> type) {
    return myObject.stream()
        .map(x-> gson.fromJson(x, type))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As you can see above, you have to provide the target class explicitly otherwise it cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you pass class object to **gson.from(x, YourClass.class)** it's works fine:

```
@Test
public void testStack() throws Exception {
    List<String> myObject = asList("{name: John}");
    Type typeObject= new TypeToken<Person>(){}.getType();
    List<Person> myTransformedObject = myObject.stream()
            .map(x-> gson.fromJson(x, Person.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    myObject.forEach(System.out::println);
}

class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am aware of that. I tried that approach out and it worked. I wanted to know what I am missing when I use a generic type.

Comment: For starters, `new TypeToken<T>() {}` just plain doesn't work when `T` is a generic type.